# Camera shows gray screen

Tags: camera

Recently I was working on creating an animation in Cycles Render, and my camera started showing only gray when I switched from the Camera View (by toggling 0) to the User Perspective. Similarly, if I try to move orthographically within the Camera View it shows only gray; here the location numbers become enormous (again, not sure why) but this doesn't occur in the User Perspective and it remains gray.  I tried to find a solution to this on the site, but the common problem and solution seems to be with clipping distance, and mine seems to be large enough. I think I toggled something by accident, but I can't determine what. The screenshots are of the different views.

[image: all is well]

[image: chaos]

[image: same problem, same distance]

Comment: It looks from your second screenshot like your camera is too far away to be included in the clipping distance. There is a huge difference in camera location between the two screenshots.

Comment: I tried taking a look at the distance to see if I could resolve it, but now the gray screen appears with the same distance numbers as the correct version.  I added another screenshot to show this

Comment: ok so I've played around some more and the same thing happens through all the layers, if that's a clue.  I tried locking the Location and Rotation, and the problem appears to be with the Location.  In the Camera View, I can lock the Rotation and then when I zoom in or out the Location shifts to numbers in the hundreds of millions.  However, I have not discovered anything else with regards to the User Perspective

Comment: can you post your blend file?

Comment: It looks like you have some keyframes which are moving the really far away from the scene, requiring an insanely huge end clip value..

Comment: I tried Shift - C and after switching to User Ortho, everything has returned to normal.  So, I'm not sure what went wrong but at least now it's fixed.  Thanks so much for all your input!

Answer (score 2):

You have to right click on *Layout* of your project and click *Delete*.
And if you want back your layout click on + button and general and layout

And your problem is solved

I think it is a glitch with that layout so you have to delete it and create another.

Comment: This worked for me on 3.4.1

Answer (score 1):

From your snapshots it looks like your camera shifted a very long distance, try to adjust the camera location or the camera clipping.